# Visual Studio DllNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

```
    public const string LIB_GVC = "gvc.dll";
    public const string LIB_GRAPH = "graph.dll";
    public const int SUCCESS = 0;


    [DllImport(LIB_GVC)]
    public static extern IntPtr gvContext();
```

Later, in the main method I call gvContext() and it throws the DllNotFoundException. In my project, I have gone into the Project->Properties and set the reference paths so that I have a folder called "resources" which contains all my DLLs including gvc.dll. I thought this would do the trick but it didn't. What do I need to do?

Note: I cannot use Add Reference as I normally would, I realize that this behavior is normal considering Graphviz is not a C# library. I'm also a bit fuzzy on terminology, why is it called an "unmanaged DLL"? It seems to be because it wasn't compiled from C# code but is that true/not the whole story?

I'm following [this tutorial](http://implicitoperator.com/blog/2009/12/24/rendering-an-in-memory-graphviz-image-with-c.html) if it helps clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the executable is not finding the path to the executable. Try placing in the /bin folder after you ahve it running and see it works. If so, you resources folder is either a) not found or b) you have a copy operation on compile that is not set up correctly.

As for "what is unmanaged", COM and Native components have their memory handled either by the library itself (native always, COM may be handled by a runtime in some instance) or by something other than .NET. The CLR cannot manage the memory usage, as they are not .NET components. That is why they are called "unmanaged".

Comment: That worked. I know how to create build rules so that all the .dlls I need will be copied into the Debug/Release folder. Is that the best approach?